# Azure Custom Vision SDK - ClientRequestError

Tags: azure, sdk, object-detection, training-data, microsoft-custom-vision

I am trying out an object detection project with the Custom Vision client library. But I get ClientRequestError. Below is my code:-

```
from azure.cognitiveservices.vision.customvision.training import CustomVisionTrainingClient 
from azure.cognitiveservices.vision.customvision.training.models import ImageFileCreateEntry
from msrest.authentication import ApiKeyCredentials

cv_endpoint = "https://westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com" 
training_key = "*******************" 
training_images = "LegoSimpsons/TrainingImages"   

credentials = ApiKeyCredentials(in_headers={"Training-key": training_key})
trainer = CustomVisionTrainingClient(credentials=credentials,endpoint=cv_endpoint)

for domain in trainer.get_domains():   
        print(domain.id, "\t", domain.name)
```

I get the below error:

> ClientRequestError: Error occurred in request., ProxyError:
> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='southcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com',
> port=443): Max retries exceeded with url:
> /customvision/v3.4-preview/training/domains (Caused by
> ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.',
> NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at
> 0x000001CA81115588>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError
> 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively
> refused it')))

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is something wrong with your `cv_endpoint`,  If you have created a Custom Vision Training service in your subscription:
[image]

you can find the key and endpoint here:
[image]

This is my test result:

[image]

Comment: I have used my endpoint the same way as you have shown above. Still, I am getting the error.